# Display Gridview SQLDatasource on Dropdownlist selected index changed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to display a gridview from a sql database using a query on a dropdownlist selected index changed for the dropdownlist.

Here is the code I currently have for this that I thought should work:

I am not getting any errors, the gridview just won't show up when i select a package from the dropdownlist.

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Package", "Select Package"));
        DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct Package_Name from dbo.PackageDetail";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Package_Name";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

}


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["datarepConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [PartNumber], [Qty], [PartDescription], [PR1], [PR2], [PR3], [EXTPR2], [EXTPR1], [EXTPR3] FROM [PackageDetail] where [Package_Name] = '" + DropDownList1.Text + "' ";
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </center>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" Height="160px" Width="374px" EnableViewState="true" >
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="PartNumber" SortExpression="PartNumber" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PartDescription" HeaderText="PartDescription" SortExpression="PartDescription" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PR1" HeaderText="PR1" SortExpression="PR1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PR2" HeaderText="PR2" SortExpression="PR2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PR3" HeaderText="PR3" SortExpression="PR3" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EXTPR2" HeaderText="EXTPR2" SortExpression="EXTPR2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EXTPR1" HeaderText="EXTPR1" SortExpression="EXTPR1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EXTPR3" HeaderText="EXTPR3" SortExpression="EXTPR3" />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Help is very appreciated thank you.

Comment: Where are you setting the Datasource for the Gridview?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? EDIT: still doesn't work

Comment: lol well thats not a good sign.  At which part of the code do you tell the GridView to 'get your data from here'. Perhaps using `GridView1.DataSource = OBJECT`.  Commonly called 'assigning a data source'...

Comment: Still doesn't work even after adding DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"

Comment: Well the Data source also has to be 'correct' too... Forget the drop down list for the moment, focus on the GridView and its datasource

Comment: I did? I added  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" Height="160px" Width="374px" EnableViewState="true">

Comment: ...and where have you defined SqlDataSource1 and connected it to your database?  Just putting the entry in ASP does nothing... You need the code to connect to the database, and to set your query etc... Please EDIT your question with this new information so that others may actually Answer ... But your question is not formed properly, thats why we are asking questions in comments